# how to load data in to a selected dashboardcomponent when header component data is changed using angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I am doing some experiment in angular. I have a header component in which I have a mat-select component.
Selected values in headercomponent will affect the components which gets loaded in the dashboard component.

Now I am selecting a value in header component then without submitting dashcomponent page also should update the field values. How can I achieve this  in angular 8 using angular material tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a BehaviorSubject Service: the dashbord componests have to subscribe to the BehaviorSubject that must be triggered by header component.

Comment: So any change in headercomponent will be reflected automatically?

Comment: Could you please share some links which helps with details ?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT I quickly created this example: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bfmwy3)

Comment: From each dashboard component's ngonit function I should write the service subscription method and related component methods as well rt?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT your dashboard component could be a base component that subscibes to changes and contains the child components (parts of dashboard) passing the changes to they